# Low Volume WCF service - cold start issue

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-6

I have a very low volume WCF web service (about 1 request in an hour or 2 - its being retired) hosted on IIS6. It connects to a DB2 database and a Websphere MQ queue. In addition to service startup, these components are also being initialized. The total response time comes to about 30 seconds. We have done the following :

1. Disabled app pool recycle
2. Initialize the service after server reboot by firing a dummy request.

We observed that in case the service gets requests after the first, the responses after initialization is around 800 ms. My question is - is there any way other than firing requests at constant interval to achieve a better response in my scenario.

Thanks
Mahesh